# How to publish company specific apps in windows phone dev center?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I want to publish a app which in company specific, i.e it requires company login and serves only company specific information.
How do i publish it to windows phone dev center so that it is available only to company's employees and not to general public for download? It it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You currently have 3 options:

### 1. Beta distibution

Advantages:

- Secure (only authorized people can install the app)

Downsides:

- Limited to 90 days

### 2. Targeted Application Distribution

> Targeted Application Distribution is the process of releasing your
>   application through App Hub while keeping it hidden on Windows Phone
>   Marketplace. You can send the link to your application to a targeted
>   set of users. Only those users who have the link to the application
>   can install it.

Advantages:

- No time limit

Downsides:

- Not very secure (anyone would be able to install the application with the link)

### 3. Company app distribution

> Windows Phone 8 enables companies to publish and distribute Windows
>   Phone apps directly to their employees or other users, bypassing the
>   Windows Phone Store. Users can install apps published by their company
>   only after they enroll their phones for app distribution from their
>   company, and only users that are enrolled for app distribution from
>   the company can install the company apps.

Advantages:

- Secure
- No time limit

Downsides:

- Windows Phone 8 only

Answer (score 2):

Regarding #2 you can still require a login so even if someone happens to guess your app's guid, they won't really be able to use the app. Note though that the person certifying the app will need a test-account to get it to the store.

## 3 is really your solution (will only cost you $299 for a company certificate + $99 store registration that you will still need even though you don't use the store directly). This session covers the details on this: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/2-014

Comment: Hi @dotMorten is there any option to do the Company app distribution without any cost(free).

Comment: No. You'll have to pay the yearly company account fee + the yearly certificate fee. However I find this extremely cheap for a proper company distributed app.